# MAAS integration with IPAM solution

Tags: maas

I'm trying to find any documentation on how MAAS might integrate with an IPAM style solution (e.g. Infoblox, BlueCat, etc.).  This would allow a centrally managed IP solution vs using various solutions each with their own IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAAS does not support integration with IPAM technologies, and unfortunately, it is not something that's within the MAAS Roadmap. Although, it does sound interesting and would probably be something for future discussion.